# Laravel Excel - How to avoid export timeout?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm trying to export some data using fromview interface.

```
public function view(): View
    {
        $this->view = "admin.reports.price_summary_export";
        $this->data = PriceReportController::getData($this->data, $this->filters, $this->rj);

        return view($this->view, ["xls" => true, "data" => $this->data, "filters" => $this->filters]);
    }
```

When $this->data is large the code will always timeout at CloseSheet. Is there any way to avoid this error?

Im a beginner in laravel so i dont understand much. So far i've tried extending the timeout to 10 minutes and it can run properly, but i dont like this solution. Im trying to find another solution for this issue

Comment: You could use [Laravel's schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling) feature. It requires the server to call the schedule command regularly once a minute. The PHP instance handling those will generally have no time restrictions. Of course then you will have to define yourself when a job is truly timed out.

Comment: Generally for long operations like this you'd use the [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) as well (or the schedule as suggested above). Whether or not this works depends on how you use this e.g. for a similar process in my site I request the user's email to be able to send the resulting file when the queue is processed. If you have similar situation it might require additional implementation

Comment: Using excel is not recommended if you are building a large file and sending it for download. You can use the stream download with `fputcsv` method to build a file and perform the download this is very fast than Excel and works perfectly too.  
This post has demo example https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-download-large-excel-with-stream-example